# For loop is several times faster in R than in Python using the rpy2 library

Tags: python, r, performance, rpy2

The following simply `for` block takes about ~3 sec to complete in `R`:

```
library(MASS)
nruns <- 2000
nelems <- 50
maxX <- 1
maxY <- 1
for(i in 1:nruns) {
    dataX <- runif(nelems, 0, maxX)
    dataY <- runif(nelems, 0, maxY)
    kde2d(dataX, dataY, n=50, lims=c(0, maxX, 0, maxY) )
}
```

The same code run in Python through the [`rpy2` library](https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/) takes between 4-5 times more:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr('MASS')

nruns = 2000
r.assign('nelems', 50)
r.assign('maxX', 1)
r.assign('maxY', 1)
for _ in range(nruns):
    r('dataX <- runif(nelems, 0, maxX)')
    r('dataY <- runif(nelems, 0, maxY)')
    r('kde2dmap <- kde2d(dataX, dataY, n=50, lims=c(0, maxX, 0, maxY))')
```

Is this just because I'm using the `rpy2` library to communicate with `R` or is there something else at play? Can this be improved in any way (while still running the code in Python)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 to 5 times slower seems a little much, but this might be the case if you are using custom conversion (rpy2 can convert R objects to arbitrary Python objects on the fly - see the doc).

Or may be you are on an HPC with a slow-ish NFS access for where your Python and packages are installed while R is on faster local disks (this could make a big difference on the startup time).

Otherwise one can also keep the loop in R to assess whether this changes the running time:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

# importr('MASS')
# Calling 'importr' will perform quite a bit of work behind the
# scene. That works allows a more intuitive/pythonic use of the
# content of the R library "MASS", but if you are just passing
# a string to be evaluated for R evaluation you can skip it
# replace it with the following:
r('library("MASS")')

nruns = 2000
r.assign('nelems', 50)
r.assign('maxX', 1)
r.assign('maxY', 1)
r.assign('nruns', nruns)
r("""
for(i in 1:nruns) {
  dataX <- runif(nelems, 0, maxX)
  dataY <- runif(nelems, 0, maxY)
  kde2dmap <- kde2d(dataX, dataY, n=50, lims=c(0, maxX, 0, maxY) )
}
""")
```

Speed improvements will come from the following:

- the code in your question is passing Python strings in each iteration. Each time that string will have to be parsed (by R) before it can be evaluated. This can amount to some overhead with long loops. In the code I am providing the parsing is performed only once.
- the code in @Parfait's answer is leveraging the fact that `importr()` creates Python object proxies for the R functions you want to use. However, there remains an overhead when creating the mapping with `importr()` (mapping are created for *all* objects in an R package), and at each iteration when going from Python to R (object checks and conversion, building of an R expression to be evaluated). Profiling the code would give you an exact breakdown of where time is spent. There exists ways to keep some of the pythonic aspects while retaining more performances. For example:

  ```
   import rpy2.rinterface as ri
   ri.initr()
   ri.baseenv['library']("MASS")
   # early bindings for R functions:
   runif = ri.globalenv.find('runif')
   kde2d = ri.globalenv.find('kde2d')
   # create constant values in loop as R objects
   maxX = ri.IntVector((1, ))
   maxY = ri.IntVector((1, ))
   nelems = ri.IntVector((50, ))
   zero = ri.IntVector((0, ))
   limits = ri.IntVector((0, maxX[0], 0, maxY[0]))
   for i in range(nruns):
       dataX = runif(nelems, zero, maxX)
       dataY = runif(nelems, zero, maxY)
       kde2dmap = kde2d(dataX, dataY, n=nelems, lims=limits)
  ```

An additional comment about performance is that rpy2's transition from C-extension to `cffi` has lead to significant improvements in the structure of the code managing the dialog with R's C API (and with that a number of tricky bugs where fixed), but at the temporary cost of performance here and there. Optimizations for speed are being progressively reintroduced.

Comment: Wow this is *a lot* faster than Parfait's answer. Their code takes ~6.5 sec to do the `importr()` lines and ~7.5 sec to do the loop. Your answer takes ~4 sec doing all that. What's going on here? Why is this so much faster? (Oh and thank you!)

Comment: Calling `importr()` should take more time than just `library()` in R. I added a note about this in my answer.

Comment: Of course, @Gabriel since lgautier is [package maintainer](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/default/) of `rpy2`. Maybe in future `rpy2` versions, R methods can implicitly convert Python types sent as parameters (int->IntVector, float->FloatVector) and `importr` can streamline mapping of packages?

Comment: @Parfait : `rpy2` is already able to automagically convert Python scalars of type `int` or `float` to R length-one vectorw. However, in this example about optimization `maxX`, `maxY`, and `nelems` are constant during the loop. Creating the corresponding R vectors once for all iterations will save a little bit extra time.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you very much to both of you!

Comment: @lgautier The line `ri.baseenv('library')("MASS")` fails with: `TypeError: 'SexpEnvironment' object is not callable`. Is it something wrong with my installation?

Comment: Typo on my end. Use square brackets (`basenv['library']`).

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, connecting to an external language API would go slower than directly running the external language. However, consider keeping everything in Python layer and avoid the `r()` calls.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr("base")
stats = importr("stats")
mass = importr("MASS")

nruns = 2000
nelems = 50
maxX = 1
maxY =  1

for _ in range(nruns):
    dataX = stats.runif(nelems, 0, maxX)
    dataY = stats.runif(nelems, 0, maxY)
    kde2dmap = mass.kde2d(dataX, dataY, n=50, lims=base.c(0, maxX, 0, maxY))
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. This is just slightly slower than the full `R` implementation. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear. No problem. If you do not need Python objects to pass into R, consider calling `subprocess` to directly run R script.